# iTunes crashes with "Attempt to allocate 1073741824 bytes for NS/CFData failed" error

Tags: macos, itunes

This is a pretty common occurrence. Every two days or so iTunes will crash on me with this error. FYI, 1073741824 is 2^30, which is gigabyte.

The crash log is below if you're interested.

---

```
Process:         iTunes [40778]
Path:            /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes
Identifier:      com.apple.iTunes
Version:         9.0.1 (9.0.1)
Build Info:      iTunes-9010901~2
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [638]

Date/Time:       2009-10-21 11:35:55.159 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.1 (10B504)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          38292 sec
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  63956 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   1
Anonymous UUID:                      A7149D8A-1161-4740-976B-DB99AE1B01DD

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  13

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSMallocException', reason: 'Attempt to allocate 1073741824 bytes for NS/CFData failed'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x9924958a __raiseError + 410
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x9440df49 objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   Foundation                          0x945e2fda _NSSearchForNameInPath + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x99262ca5 __CFDataHandleOutOfMemory + 101
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x9919f27d __CFDataGrow + 717
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x9919ce0a CFDataReplaceBytes + 362
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x9919e63a CFDataAppendBytes + 154
    7   iTunes                              0x00522808 0x0 + 5384200
    8   iTunes                              0x00523471 0x0 + 5387377
    9   iTunes                              0x00441bc8 0x0 + 4463560
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x9923eba3 _signalEventSync + 99
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x9923f58e _cfstream_solo_signalEventSync + 126
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x9923f4d7 CFReadStreamSignalEvent + 39
    13  CFNetwork                           0x97374c23 _ZN14HTTPReadStream11streamEventEm + 169
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x9923eba3 _signalEventSync + 99
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x9923eb1a _cfstream_shared_signalEventSync + 458
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x991b58cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 1563
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x991b385f __CFRunLoopRun + 1071
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x991b2d34 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x991b87a4 CFRunLoopRun + 84
    20  iTunes                              0x0000ade8 0x0 + 44520
    21  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x96de9f39 _pthread_start + 345
    22  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x96de9dbe thread_start + 34
)


Thread 0:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96dbc7da mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96dbcf47 mach_msg + 68
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x991b3dbf __CFRunLoopRun + 2447
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x991b2d34 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x991b2b61 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x97c3bfec RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 392
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x97c3bda3 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 354
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x97dc3d91 ReceiveNextEvent + 83
8   com.apple.iTunes                0x00135fae 0x1000 + 1265582
9   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x97c0f129 DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 1567
10  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x97c0e3f0 SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 411
11  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x97c0e24f SendEventToEventTargetWithOptions + 58
12  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x97c42c0c ToolboxEventDispatcherHandler(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*) + 3006
13  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x97c0f57a DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 2672
14  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x97c0e3f0 SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 411
15  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x97c30a81 SendEventToEventTarget + 52
16  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x97db98f7 ToolboxEventDispatcher + 86
17  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x97db9a2f RunApplicationEventLoop + 243
18  com.apple.iTunes                0x00135d84 0x1000 + 1265028
19  com.apple.iTunes                0x00135c70 0x1000 + 1264752
20  com.apple.iTunes                0x0000d2af 0x1000 + 49839
21  com.apple.iTunes                0x000049a8 0x1000 + 14760
22  com.apple.iTunes                0x00002bfb 0x1000 + 7163
23  com.apple.iTunes                0x00002b29 0x1000 + 6953

Thread 1:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de303a kevent + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de3768 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 215
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de2bf9 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 183
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de298a _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 234
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de2401 _pthread_wqthread + 390
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de2246 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96dbc7da mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96dbcf47 mach_msg + 68
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x991b3dbf __CFRunLoopRun + 2447
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x991b2d34 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x991b87a4 CFRunLoopRun + 84
5   com.apple.iTunes                0x0000ade8 0x1000 + 40424
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9f39 _pthread_start + 345
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9dbe thread_start + 34

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96ddb756 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x991f304d __CFSocketManager + 1085
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9f39 _pthread_start + 345
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9dbe thread_start + 34

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96e84766 accept$NOCANCEL$UNIX2003 + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96e8363e accept + 32
2   com.apple.iTunes                0x0044c792 0x1000 + 4503442
3   com.apple.iTunes                0x004a86cd 0x1000 + 4880077
4   com.apple.iTunes                0x004a879b 0x1000 + 4880283
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9f39 _pthread_start + 345
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9dbe thread_start + 34

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96e84766 accept$NOCANCEL$UNIX2003 + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96e8363e accept + 32
2   com.apple.iTunes                0x0044c792 0x1000 + 4503442
3   com.apple.iTunes                0x004a86cd 0x1000 + 4880077
4   com.apple.iTunes                0x004a879b 0x1000 + 4880283
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9f39 _pthread_start + 345
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9dbe thread_start + 34

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96dbc7da mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96dbcf47 mach_msg + 68
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x991b3dbf __CFRunLoopRun + 2447
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x991b2d34 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x991b87a4 CFRunLoopRun + 84
5   com.apple.iTunes                0x00135e09 0x1000 + 1265161
6   com.apple.iTunes                0x00135cc5 0x1000 + 1264837
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9f39 _pthread_start + 345
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9dbe thread_start + 34

Thread 7:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96dbc7da mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96dbcf47 mach_msg + 68
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x991b3dbf __CFRunLoopRun + 2447
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x991b2d34 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x991b87a4 CFRunLoopRun + 84
5   com.apple.iTunes                0x0000ade8 0x1000 + 40424
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9f39 _pthread_start + 345
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9dbe thread_start + 34

Thread 8:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96dbc83a semaphore_timedwait_signal_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96dea3c1 _pthread_cond_wait + 1066
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96e19208 pthread_cond_timedwait_relative_np + 47
3   com.apple.iTunes                0x0004ca83 0x1000 + 309891
4   com.apple.iTunes                0x0004c7cb 0x1000 + 309195
5   com.apple.iTunes                0x0004c76a 0x1000 + 309098
6   com.apple.iTunes                0x0004c5bb 0x1000 + 308667
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9f39 _pthread_start + 345
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9dbe thread_start + 34

Thread 9:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96dbc7da mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96dbcf47 mach_msg + 68
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x991b3dbf __CFRunLoopRun + 2447
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x991b2d34 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x991b87a4 CFRunLoopRun + 84
5   com.apple.iTunes                0x0000ade8 0x1000 + 40424
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9f39 _pthread_start + 345
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9dbe thread_start + 34

Thread 10:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96dbc7da mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96dbcf47 mach_msg + 68
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x991b3dbf __CFRunLoopRun + 2447
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x991b2d34 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x991b87a4 CFRunLoopRun + 84
5   com.apple.iTunes                0x0000ade8 0x1000 + 40424
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9f39 _pthread_start + 345
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9dbe thread_start + 34

Thread 11:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96dbc7da mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96dbcf47 mach_msg + 68
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x991b3dbf __CFRunLoopRun + 2447
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x991b2d34 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x991b87a4 CFRunLoopRun + 84
5   com.apple.iTunes                0x0000ade8 0x1000 + 40424
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9f39 _pthread_start + 345
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9dbe thread_start + 34

Thread 12:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96dbc822 semaphore_wait_signal_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96dea3d8 _pthread_cond_wait + 1089
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96e3370f pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   com.apple.iTunes                0x0000ae70 0x1000 + 40560
4   com.apple.iTunes                0x0000ad06 0x1000 + 40198
5   com.apple.iTunes                0x004418a1 0x1000 + 4458657
6   com.apple.iTunes                0x0043f960 0x1000 + 4450656
7   com.apple.iTunes                0x00525475 0x1000 + 5391477
8   com.apple.iTunes                0x00525c0d 0x1000 + 5393421
9   com.apple.iTunes                0x0004c62c 0x1000 + 308780
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9f39 _pthread_start + 345
11  libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9dbe thread_start + 34

Thread 13 Crashed:
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x99293b07 ___TERMINATING_DUE_TO_UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION___ + 7
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x9440df49 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x991b2fbc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 1100
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x991b87a4 CFRunLoopRun + 84
4   com.apple.iTunes                0x0000ade8 0x1000 + 40424
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9f39 _pthread_start + 345
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9dbe thread_start + 34

Thread 14:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96dbc7da mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96dbcf47 mach_msg + 68
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x991b3dbf __CFRunLoopRun + 2447
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x991b2d34 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x991b87a4 CFRunLoopRun + 84
5   com.apple.iTunes                0x0000ade8 0x1000 + 40424
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9f39 _pthread_start + 345
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9dbe thread_start + 34

Thread 15:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96dbc822 semaphore_wait_signal_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96dea3d8 _pthread_cond_wait + 1089
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96e3370f pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   ...ickTimeComponents.component  0x915275b7 jpegdecompress_MPLoop + 79
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9f39 _pthread_start + 345
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9dbe thread_start + 34

Thread 16:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96dbc822 semaphore_wait_signal_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96dea3d8 _pthread_cond_wait + 1089
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96e3370f pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   com.apple.iTunes                0x00025d27 0x1000 + 150823
4   com.apple.iTunes                0x00025237 0x1000 + 148023
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9f39 _pthread_start + 345
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9dbe thread_start + 34

Thread 17:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de2092 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de2628 _pthread_wqthread + 941
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de2246 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 18:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96dbc83a semaphore_timedwait_signal_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96dea3c1 _pthread_cond_wait + 1066
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96e19208 pthread_cond_timedwait_relative_np + 47
3   com.apple.iTunes                0x0004ca83 0x1000 + 309891
4   com.apple.iTunes                0x0004c7cb 0x1000 + 309195
5   com.apple.iTunes                0x0004c76a 0x1000 + 309098
6   com.apple.iTunes                0x0004c5bb 0x1000 + 308667
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9f39 _pthread_start + 345
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x96de9dbe thread_start + 34

Thread 13 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x00000000  ebx: 0x9440df25  ecx: 0xb08b2000  edx: 0x0000003b
  edi: 0xa0737ab0  esi: 0x19685e20  ebp: 0xb08b1de8  esp: 0xb08b1dd0
   ss: 0x0000001f  efl: 0x00000282  eip: 0x99293b07   cs: 0x00000017
   ds: 0x0000001f   es: 0x0000001f   fs: 0x0000001f   gs: 0x00000037
  cr2: 0x00ff9000

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -   0xbd9ff8  com.apple.iTunes 9.0.1 (9.0.1) <18B3F1D1-1E3E-6DD1-CB52-F346ACB01921> /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes
  0xdf9000 -   0xe01ff7  com.apple.ipodsynchronization 3.0 (116) <B41B2240-34E9-4A5E-A210-F02D99E3C00E> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iPodSync.framework/Versions/A/iPodSync
  0xe09000 -   0xe0eff7  com.apple.iPod 1.6 (17) <4CCD2720-D270-C0D2-1E14-1374779C2401> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iPod.framework/Versions/A/iPod
  0xe14000 -   0xe9bfe3  com.apple.iTunes.iPodUpdater 9.0 (9.0) <474ED35C-EDCE-1FEB-AC8C-075B806977A8> /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/Frameworks/iPodUpdater.framework/Versions/A/iPodUpdater
  0xee7000 -   0xf27ff7  com.apple.vmutils 4.2 (106) <834EA6B0-C91B-4CF1-ED3C-229C26459578> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/vmutils.framework/Versions/A/vmutils
 0x14be000 -  0x14beff7  libmx.A.dylib ??? (???) <01401BF8-3FC7-19CF-ACCE-0F292BFD2F25> /usr/lib/libmx.A.dylib
 0x14d0000 -  0x14d0ff7 +net.sourceforge.SafariAdBlockLoader 0.4.0 RC3 (0.4.0 RC3) <8E9A6641-9CE7-5416-DC84-883DB8BAFDDA> /Library/InputManagers/Safari AdBlock/Safari AdBlock Loader.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Safari AdBlock Loader
 0x15f8000 -  0x15f9ff7  com.apple.textencoding.unicode 2.3 (2.3) <78A61FD5-70EE-19EA-48D4-3481C640B70D> /System/Library/TextEncodings/Unicode Encodings.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Unicode Encodings
 0x1778000 -  0x179efff  libssl.0.9.7.dylib ??? (???) <8BF98B2F-0F55-40CA-C082-43C76707BD24> /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.7.dylib
 0x17e6000 -  0x17eaff3  com.apple.audio.AudioIPCPlugIn 1.1.0 (1.1.0) <39CD9296-183C-5603-94A4-0A0EC327BA69> /System/Library/Extensions/AudioIPCDriver.kext/Contents/Resources/AudioIPCPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AudioIPCPlugIn
 0x17ef000 -  0x17f4ffb  com.apple.audio.AppleHDAHALPlugIn 1.7.4 (1.7.4a1) <B4217DD8-4BDE-CC1C-70FF-06EA901F376D> /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn
0x12800000 - 0x138eaff7  com.apple.CoreFP 1.5.18 (1.5) <740FE25C-0539-AEFF-2108-C2C0D338CDCE> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreFP.framework/CoreFP
0x1390f000 - 0x139c4fe7  libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib ??? (???) <4917E4F2-817F-5AC4-3FBE-54BC96360448> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib
0x13a0a000 - 0x13a50ff3  com.apple.mobiledevice 251.6 (251.6) <E998830A-CFBF-3060-4770-1089AED68444> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/MobileDevice
0x167f5000 - 0x167f7ff7  com.apple.PDFImporter 2.1 (???) <C78368B0-3712-067C-9467-55932890C979> /System/Library/Components/PDFImporter.component/Contents/MacOS/PDFImporter
0x16900000 - 0x16905ff7  com.apple.QuartzComposer.iTunesPlugIn 1.2 (16) <8511A037-AFDE-5D1A-67DA-1B4837432D85> /Library/iTunes/iTunes Plug-ins/Quartz Composer Visualizer.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Quartz Composer Visualizer
0x17fa8000 - 0x181cbfe7  com.apple.audio.codecs.Components 2.0 (2.0) <064E9181-38CC-C2D3-070D-4D162D2903E8> /System/Library/Components/AudioCodecs.component/Contents/MacOS/AudioCodecs
0x18764000 - 0x1877efc3  com.apple.AppleIntermediateCodec 1.2 (145) /Library/QuickTime/AppleIntermediateCodec.component/Contents/MacOS/AppleIntermediateCodec
0x18783000 - 0x18788ff7  com.apple.AppleMPEG2Codec 1.0.1 (220) <6FDFF3C8-7ECE-CB74-1374-9C0230C54F78> /Library/QuickTime/AppleMPEG2Codec.component/Contents/MacOS/AppleMPEG2Codec
0x19137000 - 0x1918cfef  com.apple.AppleProResDecoder 2.0 (223) <793BA98A-2E7D-1C39-998D-805B60034DF4> /System/Library/QuickTime/AppleProResDecoder.component/Contents/MacOS/AppleProResDecoder
0x191c4000 - 0x191ddfe7  com.apple.applepixletvideo 1.2.19 (1.2d19) <4A68731C-8071-6CF5-012C-40F00CD1333A> /System/Library/QuickTime/ApplePixletVideo.component/Contents/MacOS/ApplePixletVideo
0x19400000 - 0x19479fef  com.apple.AppleVAH264HW.component 2.0 (1.0) <FFC0DED4-1AA1-267E-CE43-0261727DA31D> /System/Library/QuickTime/AppleVAH264HW.component/Contents/MacOS/AppleVAH264HW
0x1953b000 - 0x19577fe3  com.apple.QuickTimeFireWireDV.component 7.6.3 (1584) <8E3D38A3-1005-305C-7B70-D400AB4AC0F3> /System/Library/QuickTime/QuickTimeFireWireDV.component/Contents/MacOS/QuickTimeFireWireDV
0x1a000000 - 0x1a312fe0 +org.perian.Perian 1.1.4 (1.1.4) <577A3B05-0FF7-FC3D-3223-88718A00D84C> /Library/QuickTime/Perian.component/Contents/MacOS/Perian
0x70000000 - 0x700cbfe7  com.apple.audio.units.Components 1.6 (1.6) <A568FC6D-1D2D-A04B-FD1A-AFF6E326E020> /System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/MacOS/CoreAudio
0x8fe00000 - 0x8fe4162b  dyld 132.1 (???) <211AF0DD-42D9-79C8-BB6A-1F4BEEF4B4AB> /usr/lib/dyld
0x900cb000 - 0x900ccff7  com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit 1.6 (1.6) <68180B96-381C-A09D-5576-606A134FD953> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
0x900cd000 - 0x908b2fe7  com.apple.WebCore 6531 (6531.9) <F9A9848B-9EB0-B912-49F5-7E8010AF2CF1> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/WebCore.framework/Versions/A/WebCore
0x908b3000 - 0x908effff  com.apple.CoreMediaIOServices 101.0 (715) <FD86FB28-9BA1-0993-1172-F10F61EA6344> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMediaIOServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreMediaIOServices
0x9095f000 - 0x90970ff7  com.apple.LangAnalysis 1.6.5 (1.6.5) <E77440D0-76EE-EB4C-3D00-9EDE417F13CF> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
0x909ba000 - 0x90bb7feb  com.apple.AddressBook.framework 5.0 (862) <BD05B213-46CF-8EFD-B801-CF741408600D> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/Versions/A/AddressBook
0x90bd9000 - 0x90c03ff7  com.apple.shortcut 1.1 (1.1) <B0514FA9-7CAE-AD94-93CA-7B2A2C5F7B8A> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Shortcut.framework/Versions/A/Shortcut
0x90c04000 - 0x90c23fe7  com.apple.opencl 11 (11) <372A42E7-FB10-B74D-E1A0-980E94D07021> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL
0x90c24000 - 0x90c24ff7  com.apple.Accelerate 1.5 (Accelerate 1.5) <F642E7A0-3720-FA19-0190-E6DBD9EF2D9B> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
0x90c25000 - 0x90c25ff7  com.apple.ApplicationServices 38 (38) <8012B504-3D83-BFBB-DA65-065E061CFE03> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
0x90d7c000 - 0x90db6fe7  libFontRegistry.dylib ??? (???) <EE633CF6-8827-EF05-10A4-5F2937120227> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontRegistry.dylib
0x90db7000 - 0x91d45ff7  com.apple.QuickTimeComponents.component 7.6.3 (1584) /System/Library/QuickTime/QuickTimeComponents.component/Contents/MacOS/QuickTimeComponents
0x91d46000 - 0x91d7cfff  libtidy.A.dylib ??? (???) <DDFAB560-3883-A6A2-7BDD-D91730982B48> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x91d8d000 - 0x91d92ff7  com.apple.OpenDirectory 10.6 (10.6) <92582807-E8F3-3DD9-EB42-4195CFB754A1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/OpenDirectory
0x91d93000 - 0x91d9aff7  com.apple.agl 3.0.12 (AGL-3.0.12) <6BF89127-C18C-27A9-F94A-981836A822FE> /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL
0x91d9b000 - 0x91ddbff3  com.apple.securityinterface 4.0 (36981) <F024C5CA-0762-1599-5BAB-17F785E51075> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityInterface.framework/Versions/A/SecurityInterface
0x91e0d000 - 0x91e5dfe7  libGLU.dylib ??? (???) <55A69DCE-1237-341E-F239-CDFE1F5B19BB> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib
0x91e5e000 - 0x91ee0ffb  SecurityFoundation ??? (???) <29C27E0E-B2B3-BF6B-B1F8-5783B8B01535> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/SecurityFoundation
0x91f28000 - 0x9235dff7  libLAPACK.dylib ??? (???) <5E2D2283-57DE-9A49-1DB0-CD027FEFA6C2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
0x9236b000 - 0x9237ffe7  libbsm.0.dylib ??? (???) <14CB053A-7C47-96DA-E415-0906BA1B78C9> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x923bb000 - 0x924e4fe7  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox 1.6 (1.6) <62BEEBE6-68FC-4A48-91CF-39DA2BD793F1> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
0x924fe000 - 0x925b0ffb  libFontParser.dylib ??? (???) <EB089832-660F-0B34-3AC8-CCDA937987D9> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib
0x9264d000 - 0x9264fff7  libRadiance.dylib ??? (???) <0E03CF64-0931-7B9A-F617-4387B809D6D8> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRadiance.dylib
0x92650000 - 0x92696ff7  libauto.dylib ??? (???) <FAB17F30-A28B-E33D-6E21-C7119C9C83ED> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
0x92697000 - 0x928c2ff3  com.apple.QuartzComposer 4.0 (156.6) <D1D3A5A8-75BC-4556-85FA-8A9F487106DD> /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QuartzComposer.framework/Versions/A/QuartzComposer
0x928c3000 - 0x92913ff7  com.apple.framework.familycontrols 2.0 (2.0) <50617342-E578-4C1C-938A-19A37ECA91CA> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyControls.framework/Versions/A/FamilyControls
0x92914000 - 0x92c0dfef  com.apple.QuickTime 7.6.3 (1584) <687233E1-F428-5224-08D5-5874BEA2300D> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickTime.framework/Versions/A/QuickTime
0x92c22000 - 0x92d62ff7  com.apple.syncservices 5.0 (575) <61B36E07-6D14-97DC-122F-41EDE1F6DB03> /System/Library/Frameworks/SyncServices.framework/Versions/A/SyncServices
0x92d6e000 - 0x92d9fff3  libTrueTypeScaler.dylib ??? (???) <F326E053-7425-2F10-F883-CBD56A1E1B72> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTrueTypeScaler.dylib
0x92da0000 - 0x92dc0fe7  libresolv.9.dylib ??? (???) <A48921CB-3FA7-3071-AF9C-2D86FB493A3A> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x92dca000 - 0x92ed7ff7  com.apple.MediaToolbox 0.420.17 (420.17) <EE843140-C79F-3D8C-B89E-893CD74C3633> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/Versions/A/MediaToolbox
0x92f4a000 - 0x92ff9fe3  com.apple.QuickTimeImporters.component 7.6.3 (1584) <34BF4FBA-BFCD-9A47-4BA9-E2B155C5C881> /System/Library/QuickTime/QuickTimeImporters.component/Contents/MacOS/QuickTimeImporters
0x92ffa000 - 0x930a9fef  com.apple.ColorSync 4.6.0 (4.6.0) <66ABAE86-B0EC-D641-913D-08ACA965F9FA> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
0x930aa000 - 0x931a0ff7  libGLProgrammability.dylib ??? (???) <B8E40851-3A01-7D01-2F96-537BF7FA63B5> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x931a8000 - 0x93200fe7  com.apple.datadetectorscore 2.0 (80.7) <A40AA74A-9D13-2A6C-5440-B50905923251> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/Versions/A/DataDetectorsCore
0x93201000 - 0x93228ff7  com.apple.quartzfilters 1.6.0 (1.6.0) <879A3B93-87A6-88FE-305D-DF1EAED04756> /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QuartzFilters.framework/Versions/A/QuartzFilters
0x93229000 - 0x9327aff7  com.apple.HIServices 1.8.0 (???) <B8EC13DB-A81A-91BF-8C82-66E840C64C91> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
0x9327b000 - 0x932b6fe7  com.apple.DebugSymbols 1.1 (70) <05013716-CFCF-801E-5535-D0643869BDCD> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DebugSymbols.framework/Versions/A/DebugSymbols
0x932b7000 - 0x93304feb  com.apple.DirectoryService.PasswordServerFramework 6.0 (6.0) <BF66BA5D-BBC8-78A5-DBE2-F9DE3DD1D775> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PasswordServer.framework/Versions/A/PasswordServer
0x93305000 - 0x93319ffb  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework 3.10.35 (3.10.35) <57DD5458-4F24-DA7D-0927-C3321A65D743> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
0x9331a000 - 0x9335eff3  com.apple.coreui 0.2 (112) <A810DFFD-6314-5E2B-93A4-D5626634B1EE> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/CoreUI
0x9335f000 - 0x93418fe7  libsqlite3.dylib ??? (???) <16CEF8E8-8C9A-94CD-EF5D-05477844C005> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x93419000 - 0x93473ff7  com.apple.framework.IOKit 2.0 (???) <7618DDEC-2E3B-9C6E-FDC9-15169E24B4FB> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x93474000 - 0x934edff3  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 3.2.0 (3.2) <91AE891E-6015-AABE-3512-2D5EBCA0937B> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
0x934ee000 - 0x935effe7  libxml2.2.dylib ??? (???) <C242A74D-280A-90C3-3F79-891624AA45D2> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x935f0000 - 0x93634fe7  com.apple.Metadata 10.6.0 (507.1) <CBD1B22B-5F10-C784-03A2-35106B97DF3F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
0x93635000 - 0x93637ff7  com.apple.QuickTimeH264.component 7.6.3 (1584) /System/Library/QuickTime/QuickTimeH264.component/Contents/MacOS/QuickTimeH264
0x93639000 - 0x93654ff7  libPng.dylib ??? (???) <38DD4AA1-0643-85A0-F2F5-EE9269729975> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
0x93655000 - 0x936affe7  com.apple.CorePDF 1.0 (1.0) <590244C9-15D7-7A65-13AF-6F597123746B> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CorePDF.framework/Versions/A/CorePDF
0x936b0000 - 0x936e8ff7  com.apple.LDAPFramework 2.0 (120.1) <8C7F3F42-6A4D-D37A-4232-685D44E8769E> /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP
0x93723000 - 0x93757ff7  libcups.2.dylib ??? (???) <9078BA07-DEE1-6597-D15D-7BE3A20CB5A0> /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
0x93758000 - 0x93758ff7  liblangid.dylib ??? (???) <B99607FC-5646-32C8-2C16-AFB5EA9097C2> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x93759000 - 0x9375cffb  com.apple.help 1.3.1 (41) <67F1F424-3983-7A2A-EC21-867BE838E90B> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Help.framework/Versions/A/Help
0x9375d000 - 0x937d4feb  com.apple.backup.framework 1.1 (1.0) <73C642BD-
```

Comment: I hope you're reporting this to Apple as well?

Comment: Every time. It's been happening for a while now, since well before Snow Leopard was released. I'm imagining it has something to do with something unique about my system, the external drives or some faulty plugin or something.

Comment: Have you tried removing any plugins, does it only occur with your user account?

Comment: Run Apple Hardware Test and/or memtest.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of SafariAdBlock and any other InputManagers you've thrown on your system. If you need help finding them, run this:

http://khiltd.com/software/consultants_canary

Comment: That wasn't it, either. The only input manager I had installed was AdBlock, removing it didn't help. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you reading any http net-radio or video streams using iTunes?

The _ZN14HTTPReadStream11streamEventEm function appears in the callstack shortly after  __CFRunLoopDoSources0 is called. The latter probably examines the status of known streaming sources and subsequently calls the former upon noticing that there is indeed something worth streaming.

I can only assume that there are invalid data inside the stream which the streaming code doesn't handle properly, leading to an absurd memory allocation instead of ignoring the faulty data.

Try to notice which audio/video sources you are playing from when this bug appears. If you can pinpoint one that systematically causes it, you should then include its URL in your next Apple Crash Report.

Note that this crash implies up to two bugs in iTunes' code:

- Failure to handle invalid data (this one is only probable).
- Failure to properly handle Out Of Memory exceptions.

(and I'm pretty naive to reply to a one year old question, but well, you never know :) )